# double free or corruption (out) on ipiv magma_getrs_gpu

Tags: c++, lapack, magma

I have the following code:

```
magma_int_t *h_ipiv;
magma_imalloc_cpu( &h_ipiv,  k);

for (i=0;i<k;i++){
    h_ipiv[i] = i;
}
magma_dgemm(MagmaTrans, MagmaNoTrans, N, n, m, 1.0, d_G2, m, d_A2, m, 0.0, d_QA, N, queue);

magma_dgemm(MagmaTrans, MagmaNoTrans, N, n, m, 1.0, d_G1, m, d_A1, m, -1.0, d_QA, N, queue);

magma_int_t info_getrs;
magma_dgetrs_gpu(MagmaTrans, Ngaps, n, d_M, N, h_ipiv, d_QA, N, &info_getrs);
```

On the last line I am getting an error `double free or corruption (out): 0x000000001dd18540`. I checked the arrays from `magma_dgemm` and they seem to be correct. Sizes are also correct because I had this code on cpu lapack version and they were the same. So the error seems to be on `h_ipiv`, but I have no clue on what is wrong with `h_ipiv`.

Any idea?

Comment: why are you doing a malloc on `h_ipiv` of length `k` elements, when `k` doesn't show up anywhere in your call to `magma_dgetrs_gpu` ?  The expected value for the length of `h_ipiv` is `Ngaps`, the same `Ngaps` as [used in the 2nd parameter](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projectsfiles/magma/doxygen/group__magma__getrs.html#gad47641fbef3233404e0164b1a3c5d336) to the `magma_dgetrs_gpu` call.  If `k` < `Ngaps`, that is probably the issue. You are supposed to have one pivot entry per row in your matrix.

Comment: Hi @RobertCrovella, thanks for your answer. It's not written here but k is the same value as Ngaps. So that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. Unlike lapack, in magma, to create `ipiv` for `dgetrs_gpu` we have to use before `dgetrf_gpu`.

So the solution is just adding the following lines before the function dgetrs_gpu:

```
magma_int_t info_getrf;
magma_dgetrf_gpu(Ngaps, Ngaps, d_M, Ngaps, h_ipiv, &info_getrf);
```